# Facebook PHP SDK API and Url Rewrite

Tags: php, facebook, api, mod-rewrite, redirect

I've searched quite thouroughly but can't find a proper answer so here I am, asking support for the first time about this API.

I am using Zend Framework to develop a mobile web application that also integrates a part of Facebook. So I started digging into the Facebook PHP SDK, and got my url and library working. The one problem I come across is that when Facebook acknowledges the login, it redirects with the known blabla.bla/?blabla= get parameters. Zend Framework however operates by using Url Rewrite, so these two collide.

I can't find an option for Facebook to use an Url Rewrite friendly response, is there a way to get Facebook to do this for me, or am I supposed to create a stand alone response page to redirect the proper Url Rewrite?

Best regards,

Casper

Answer (score 0):

There is no such a thing as URL "friendly option", if you are having problems, it has to be with the URL that you are giving Facebook for the redirect, and the method you are using to get the variable content.

Zend framework can work with variables sent using "pretty" URLs, or normal requests, you can use the zend version that is something like this:

```
$this->getRequest()->getParam('your_param_name');
```

Or the normal one

```
$_GET["your_param_name"]
```

In you action and it will work just fine.

Take a look at the complete documentation here:

http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.request.html